# Add a single row with multiple columns to html table in d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, d3.js

I am using the below code to add a table to my d3 chart.

```
 function tabulate(data, columns) {
      const table = d3.select('body').append('table')
      const thead = table.append('thead')
      const tbody = table.append('tbody');

      // append the header row
      thead.append('td')
        .selectAll('th')
        .data(columns).enter()
        .append('th')
        .text((column) => column);

      // // create a row for each object in the data
      const rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

      // create a cell in each row for each column
      const cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data((row) => {
          return columns.map((column) => {
            return { column: [column], value: row[column] };
          });
        })
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .text((d) => d.value);

        return table;
    }
```

I need to add a vertical heading to the table and read each key from a json object into multiple columns in a single row. How can this be acheived in d3? Please help.

Comment: Can you show us your `data` object?

Comment: Below is my data model from json: export interface ZRTData {
    A: string;
    B: number;
    C: number;
    D_percentage: number;
   
} I need to add a single row with heading D_percentage and values from JSON under a d3 chart. I need to add a vertical heading and a single row with multiple columns with different D_percentage values from json.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an nice example, using the same function `tabulate` as you have: [Basic D3 Table](http://bl.ocks.org/yan2014/c9dd6919658991d33b87)